# jQuery passing variable strange syntax

Tags: jquery, argument-passing

I have the following two functions:

```
$(".content").click( function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $.get("InfoRetrieve", { theid:id }, addContent );
});

function addContent(data){
    $("#0001").append(data);
}
```

I need to pass the 'id' variable from the first function to the addContent function, I don't quite get how this works. In the above example I am passing the "data" variable to the addContent function implicitly (it seems). Will I do something like this:

In the first function
addContent -- becomes --> addContent(id)

In the second function

addContent(data) -- becomes --> addContent(data,id)

or something completely different?

**Edit:** I made modifications as per Denis' suggestion, however now it seems as if nothing happens - previously I had sone some hard coding so I was able to see my "data" being appended to the proper place:

```
$(".content").click( function() {
var id = this.id;
$.get("InfoRetrieve", { theid:id }, addContent {addContent(data, id)}  );
});

function addContent(data, id){
alert(id);
$("#0001").append(data);
}
```

**Another edit** Firefox says: 

missing ) after argument list
[Break on this error] $.get("InfoRetrieve", { theid:id ..., addContent {addContent(data, id)} );\n 
.... but this doesn't seem to make sense since as far as I can see all the brackets match up with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.get("InfoRetrieve", { theid:id }, function(data) {addContent(data, id)} );
```

Comment: Hi Deniss, thanks for your help. But that didn't seem to work. I have updated the question.

Comment: the code in your update looks nothing like deniss' suggestion, which should definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".content").click( function() {
  var id = this.id;
  $.get("InfoRetrieve", { theid:id }, function() {
    addContent(data, id);
  });
});

function addContent(data, id){
  alert(id);
  $("#0001").append(data);
}
```